# Overconstrained properties: Non-compliant browser behaviour?

Tags: html, css

According to [Eric Meyer](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012726.do) and the CSS specification following must hold...

`margin-left + border-width + padding-left + width + padding-right + margin-right = width of containing block`

... i.e. sum of the horizontal properties of a block box must be equal to the width of the containing block.

❗If both horizontal margins (`margin-left` and `margin-right`) and the width of an element are set then the properties are said to be "overconstrained" and the browser must override `margin-right` and set it to `auto`. **However, I fail to replicate this behaviour.** Take this example:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
}

p {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>PARAGRAPH</p>
</div>
```

When I inspect the paragraph the right margin is still 100px. Why is that? Am I missing something? Can you replicate this?

Comment: @Laif Not sure I'm following you 

Comment: Just teasing, I personally couldn't fathom reading a book about CSS nor proceeding to test such a fringe concept mentioned in said book. Keep doing what you're doing though.

Comment: It's actually an awful book to read, so I do agree with you. I just don't know how else I would learn the atrocity that is CSS. The reason I'm mainly reading this book is to be aware of all the quirks that CSS offers.

Answer (score 0):

When an element becomes overconstrained, the left margin is set to auto, not the right.

> In the rare cases where width is overconstrained (i.e., when all of width, margin-left, border, padding, the content area, and margin-right are defined), margin-left is ignored, and will have the same calculated value as if the auto value was specified. -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left

Comment: Apparently it depends on the flow direction (left-to-right or right-to-left)

Comment: I suppose, but the only way to achieve right to left flow is by non standard means, I was answering based on only the elements without anything else. Consider closing this question or marking it as answered if you've come to a conclusion.

Comment: I don't consider it answered because I can't replicate what is said on the MDN article either.